# Textbooks on Matrix Calculus?

Tags: references, matrix, matrix-calculus

See [this question on Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1111504/differentiation-with-respect-to-a-matrix-residual-sum-of-squares).

Short story: I read *The Elements of Statistical Learning* and got frustrated when I was trying to verify some of the results, e.g., given
$$\text{RSS}(\beta) = \left(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta\right)^{T}\left(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta\right)\text{,}$$
then
$$\begin{align}&\dfrac{\partial\text{RSS}}{\partial \beta} = -2\mathbf{X}^{T}\left(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\beta\right) \\
&\dfrac{\partial^2\text{RSS}}{\partial \beta\text{ }\partial \beta^{T}} = 2\mathbf{X}^{T}\mathbf{X}\text{.}
\end{align}$$
I am looking for a matrix calculus book which is written like your traditional calculus book (i.e., proofs of theorems, examples, exercises on computation, etc.). I have already seen [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68453/resources-for-matrix-calculus-for-optimization) and feel that the text by Magnus and Neudecker focuses too much on the theory, and the text I have by [Gentle](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387708723) focuses too little on the theory and too much on the computation side.

Is there a happy medium out there which is accessible to someone with a background in undergraduate analysis?

Comment: Have you considered Harville's, [Matrix Algebra from a statisticians perspective](http://www.amazon.com/Matrix-Algebra-From-Statisticians-Perspective/dp/038794978X)? The first chapters should be relatively elementary but then it picks up.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Matrix-Algebra-Econometric-Exercises-Vol/dp/0521537460/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1429493192&sr=1-2&keywords=jan+magnus

Comment: I often use this Wikipedia entry to find identities of matrix calculus problems: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For most matrix questions I always first refer to "The Matrix Cookbook" (see [here](http://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.imm.dtu.dk%2Fpubdb%2Fviews%2Fedoc_download.php%2F3274%2Fpdf%2Fimm3274.pdf&ei=OFI3VY3CLobuPI2QgLAH&usg=AFQjCNFJbycDGy_rsijRk8x9LE8C1v4Mpw&bvm=bv.91071109,d.ZWU&cad=rja)).

It is regularly updated due to feedback from various sources. There are proofs contained within, however it is mostly intended as a handbook.

Comment: I too, but I need a more detailed version. With more proofs

Answer (score 3):

If you found too much theory in the book of Magnus and Neudecker, I recommend this one, also authored by Magnus:

Abadir, K.M. and Magnus, J.R.
Matrix Algebra
Cambridge University Press, 2005

that has more emphasis on the applications of matrix calculus.

Answer (score 3):

I would highly recommend this 26 pages paper from Stanford University:

["*Linear Algebra Review and Reference*" by Zico Kolter](http://cs229.stanford.edu/section/cs229-linalg.pdf)

It really focus on **typical Sum calculations** with a lot of i and j everywhere and tells you the **corresponding matrix calculation** (i.e. using their "vectorized" implementation).

It helps you **recognize right away** what type of matrix formula you should write to do your calculations.

Answer (score 3):

A user self-deleted the following helpful answer, which I here reproduce in full so that its information is not lost:

> You don't really need a lot of results on vector and matrix derivatives for ML, and [Tom Minka's paper](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/minka/papers/matrix/minka-matrix.pdf) covers most of it, but the definitive treatment is Magnus & Neudecker's [Matrix Differential Calculus with Applications in Statistics and Econometrics](http://amzn.com/047198633X).

Indeed, Magnus & Neudecker has excellent reviews on Amazon and Tom Minka's paper (*Old and New Matrix Algebra Useful for Statistics*, 2000) contains many useful formulas, although he warns "this is advanced material."